# How to use routes in flutter to navigate to page other than from main?

Tags: flutter

I created a route for navigating from one page to another, in the following way

```
class task extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Task',
        home: new task(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/Completed": (BuildContext context) => new Completed()

        }
    );
  }
}


class taskScreen extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  taskState createState() => new taskState();
}


class taskState extends State<taskScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    Column taskScreen = Column(
        children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
              ..,
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/Completed");  
               },
              child: Text(
              "Completed",
              ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ]);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Task Screen')),
      body: taskScreen,
    );
  }

}
```

However when i try navigating it gives the error :

Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/Completed", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

How can I fix this error?

I have used implemented route before from my main.dart page to the second page which worked properly however its not working here.

Comment: where did you define the Completed() class, i think you are returning null there?

Comment: @SamiKanafani Nope I am not. i am returning a Scaffold app view !
I defined it in a separate dart file and importing into this.

Comment: could plz show the code of the Completed class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Completed");
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error. Instead of instantiating task(),i had created an instance of taskScreen(). Hence the new route was never set. It solved my issue but I'm still curious as to what difference it made as both of them gave the same output Screen.