# Flutter : Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/HomePage", null) in the _WidgetsAppState

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm using the following in my demo project for routes:

```
 routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/HomePage': (BuildContext context) => HomePage()
  },
```

And trying to navigate home screen using the following code:

```
onPressed: () {
    debugPrint("Hello button is clicked");

     Navigator.of(context)
               .pushReplacementNamed('/HomePage');
 },
```

But When my button clicked I'm getting the following Exception:

```
════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/HomePage", null) in the _WidgetsAppState.

Generators for routes are searched for in the following order:
 1. For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used.
 2. Otherwise, the "routes" table is used, if it has an entry for the route.
 3. Otherwise, onGenerateRoute is called. It should return a non-null value for any valid route not handled by "home" and "routes".
 4. Finally if all else fails onUnknownRoute is called.
Unfortunately, onUnknownRoute was not set.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:772:9)
#1      _WidgetsAppState._onUnknownRoute (package:flutter/src/widgets/app.dart:785:6)
#2      NavigatorState._routeNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1625:22)
#3      NavigatorState.pushReplacementNamed (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1690:35)
#4      _RegisterPage.build.<anonymous closure> (package:oricon/register.dart:231:42)
```

> I have already checked below Stack-overflow links

- [Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/", null) in the _WidgetsAppState](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58909129/8112541)
- [How to use routes in flutter to navigate to page other than from main?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56233077/8112541)
- [Could not find a generator for route "home-page" in the _MaterialAppState](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52405521/8112541)
- [Why does it not work when I use pushNamedReplacement instead of pushReplacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57146482/8112541)

If you need more information, please do let me know.

Answer (score 19):

try this

```
 Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed("/HomePage");
```

Comment: official doc is useless. this is good.

Comment: awesome men this just worked fine for me

Comment: This saved me so much hardship

Answer (score 7):

You can use instead of:

```
Navigator.of(context)
           .pushReplacementNamed('/HomePage');
```

Use this:

```
 Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => new MyHomePage())
 );
```

As you can see in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52406650/13384125), this worked for me

Comment: I think we can use both here

Comment: Makes no difference either way for me.

Answer (score 6):

Are you implementing to the main Class that's receiving your paths?

Here's an example:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp()); //as you can see here, it is the main widget

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Home Page'),
      routes: {
        'profile': (context) => ProfilePage(),
         /*Here's where you receive your routes, and it is also the main widget*/
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Also, I have to add that your question helped me find what was going wrong with my code. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

you didn't register your route in main.dart file

Comment: I did register the route and it still happens (only on iOS).

Answer (score 0):

You can search for MaterialApp in your code (Do not consider Plugin code), and also give arguments if you are using pushName navigator that can avoid the null problem.

Please check this **[two MaterialApp](https://dev.to/zeeshanmehdi/flutter-could-not-find-a-generator-for-route-routesettings-somepage-null-in-the-widgetsappstate-2pcp)** .

Answer (score 0):

I had navigation drawer and one of my route was going to a route which had another MaterialApp() Widget and after routing to that page if i route back to any other page it will through this exception.

because the context was changed to new material app and i was trying to find that route inside new material app but obviously it was not present there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30933849)